# Need to split string with # in obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

my string is like 
:

```
NSString * string = @"Had a #great#ftr time at the ####party @last ?night.";
NSError * error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"((#.+?\\b)|(.+?(?=#|$)))"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&error];
NSArray * matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches ) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [string substringWithRange:[match range]]);
}
```

**output is :**

Had a 
"#great"
"#ftr"
time at the 
"####"
party @last ?night.

And i need :

output is :

Had a 
 "#great "
"#ftr"
time at the 
"##"
"#party @last ?night."

in short i need to create hash tag from this string.

Comment: Can you show what output you want? Not sure what the question is here?

Comment: @Fogmeister i need to create hash tag means i want to separate string with #attached to some string .

Comment: that would collect you all 'valid' hashtags: `(#{1}\w+)`, in your sample string those are _#great_, _#ftr_ and _#party_.

Comment: is this the format you want it:Had a  #great #ftr  time at the  #### party @last ?night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that lists all hastags from e.g. your sample string.

I don't know whether that is what you really look for, but I might be a good start if it is not your final achievement.

```
NSString *_string = @"Had a #great#ftr time at the ####party @last ?night.";
NSError *_error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *_regExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(#{1}\\w+)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&_error];
[_regExp enumerateMatchesInString:_string options:NSMatchingProgress range:NSMakeRange(0, _string.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([result numberOfRanges] > 0) {
        NSString *_tempHashtag = [_string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:0]];
        NSLog(@"%@", _tempHashtag);
    }
}];
```

**OR**, if you prefer better to collect all matches first:

```
NSString *_string = @"Had a #great#ftr time at the ####party @last ?night.";
NSError *_error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *_regExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(#{1}\\w+)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&_error];
NSArray *_matches = [_regExp matchesInString:_string options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, _string.length)];
[_matches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult  * obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    If ([obj numberOfRanges] > 0) {
        NSString *_tempHashtag = [_string substringWithRange:[obj rangeAtIndex:0]];
        NSLog(@"%@", _tempHashtag);
    }
}];
```

**OR**, if you would not like to overcomplicate it as I did above:

```
NSString *_string = @"Had a #great#ftr time at the ####party @last ?night.";
NSError *_error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *_regExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(#{1}\\w+)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&_error];
NSArray *_matches = [_regExp matchesInString:_string options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, _string.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult * match in _matches ) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [_string substringWithRange:[match range]]);
}
```

the result on the console is in all cases:

```
#great
#ftr
#party
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what your looking for, but this is the code i used in my app for hash tags, it gets all string with with HashTag or "@", Tweeter like, and colours them in a different color. 
Of course you could add them to an array or whatever else you want..

```
//Color:
+ (NSAttributedString *)attributedMessageFromMessage:(NSString *)message {
    NSArray* messageWords = [message componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedMessage = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];

    for (NSString *word in messageWords) {
        NSDictionary * attributes;
        if ([word isEqualToString:@""] || !word) {
            return attributedMessage;
        }


        if([word characterAtIndex:0] == '@'){
            attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:72.0/255.0
                                                                          green:192.0/255.0
                                                                           blue:89.0/255.0
                                                                          alpha:1.0],
                           wordType: userNameKey,
                           userNameKey:[word substringFromIndex:1],
                            NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:18.0f]};

        } else if([word characterAtIndex:0] == '#'){
            attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:16.0/255.0
                                                                          green:96.0/255.0
                                                                           blue:184.0/255.0
                                                                          alpha:1.0],
                           wordType: hashTagKey,
                           hashTagKey:[word substringFromIndex:1],
                            NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:18.0f]};

        } else {
            attributes = @{
                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:145.0/255.0 green:145.0/255.0  blue:145.0/255.0  alpha:1], wordType: normalKey,
                           NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:18.0f]};


        }
        NSAttributedString * subString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                          initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",word]
                                          attributes:attributes];





        [attributedMessage appendAttributedString:subString];




    }
    return attributedMessage;
}
```

Hope this helps